# Call by reference of a string with double pointer

Tags: c, string, pass-by-reference

Hi guys I got some problems with using a function with a reference to a string as argument. I read that you should use e double pointer for this, but I can't get it to work.
This is (partly) my code.

```
enum errCode { ERR_NONE = 0, ERR_EMPTY, ERR_FULL, ERR_MEM, ERR_INIT, ERR_COMMAND, ERR_UNDEFINED };
typedef enum errCode ErrCode;

typedef enum {
    no = 0, add, del, src, show, exit
} Command;

int main(void) {
    char stringval[50];
    char stringval2[50];
    ErrCode err;
    Command currentCommand = no;

    printf("Enter a command\n");

    if (fgets(stringval, 50, stdin) != NULL) {
        char *p;
        if ((p = strchr(stringval, '\n')) != NULL)
            *p = '\0';
    }

    ErrHandler(
            extractCommand(&currentCommand, stringval, &stringval2)
            );

    printf("stringval 2 = %s.\n", stringval2);

    return 0;
}

ErrCode extractCommand(Command *command, char *inputString, char **outputString) {

    char *strTemp;
    char *strTemp2;

    //Get the first word of the string
    strTemp = strtok(inputString, " ");

    strTemp2 = strtok(NULL, " ");
    *outputString = strTemp2;

    //Check if it equals a command
    if (strcmp(strTemp, "exit") == 0) {
        *command = exit;
        return ERR_NONE;
    } else if (strcmp(strTemp, "add") == 0) {
        *command = add;
        return ERR_NONE;
    } else if (strcmp(strTemp, "del") == 0) {
        *command = del;
        return ERR_NONE;
    } else if (strcmp(strTemp, "src") == 0) {
        *command = src;
        return ERR_NONE;
    } else if (strcmp(strTemp, "show") == 0) {
        *command = show;
        return ERR_NONE;
    } else {
        *command = no;
        printf("%s", strTemp);
        return ERR_COMMAND;
    }
}
```

This is what my output looks like:

```
Enter a command
add this is a test
stringval 2 = z˜ˇøÀo‡èK‡èT¯ˇø.
```

I obviously want to have the second word of the inputted string, but I'm doing something wrong.
Thx for the help!

Comment: Aren't you getting any compiler warnings? Try compiling with -Wall option and let us know what the warning messages are.

Comment: That shouldn't even compile. `&stringval2` is a pointer to an array, not a pointer to a pointer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stringVal2` is not initialised and is never populated: that is reason junk is being printed. There is no need in this case to pass a `char**`, passing a `char*` will work. However, this:

```
outputString = strTemp2;
```

does not copy the content of `strTemp2` to `outputString`: it makes `outputString` point to the same address as `strTemp2`: use `strcpy()`.

---

A double pointer, `char**` for example, is commonly passed to a function when that function allocates a new buffer for the argument (which is not the case in the posted code):

```
char* buf = NULL;
my_alloc(&buf);

void my_alloc(char** p)
{
    *p = malloc(10);
}
```

Comment: No problem and welcome to stack overflow. Just to point out that if an answer solves your problem it is normal to accept the answer (by clicking the white tick to the left of the answer). But only accept it if it answers the question and is the best answer (so it may be worth waiting to see if anyone else posts a more useful answer).